# Mean of a discrete random variable

Tags: probability, expectation, means

How can we calculate the mean of a discrete random variable like for the continuous case where we integrate $xf(x)$?

Comment: You just take each individual probability, multiply it by the corresponding value and sum. The continuous integral is what happens in the limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to weigh each possible outcome with the probability of that outcome and then sum, i.e.
$$\sum_{i=1}^Np_ix_i$$
is the expected value of a random variable $X$ that has $N$ possible outcomes in the form of the set $\{x_i\}$. $p_i$ is the probability that $x_i$ happens. As you can see, it is very similar to the continuous case.